# Fix SQL subquery return multiple row

Tags: sql, oracle

I am running this query with oracle but I get the famous oracle error  `ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row`

```
Select
  DISTINCT s1.cityArrival,
  s2.cityDeparture,
  s2.sectionStartDate,
  userFirstName
FROM
  sections s1,
  sections s2,
  trajectory t,
  userInfo
WHERE
  s1.trajectId = s2.trajectId
  AND t.trajectId = s1.trajectId
  AND (
    s1.cityArrival = 'Paris'
    AND s2.cityDeparture = 'Rochelle'
  )
  AND driverMail = mailUser
  AND (
    Select
      availableSeats
    FROM
      sections s3
    WHERE
      s3.trajectId = s1.trajectId
      AND s2.sectionId <= s3.sectionId
      AND s3.sectionId <= s1.sectionId
  ) not IN (0)
```

I want to select the trajectories given a date and a city of arrival and city of departure having for each section an availableSeats > 0. The problem is that I cannot find a way to do this without for loop in sql and it becomes complicated.

SectionId is just the index of the enroute city in a proposed trajectory, that is why I can use it to get all the chuncks between two given destination.

NB: I made the design of the DB, if you have remarks on the design don't hesitate to tell me, Thanks in advance

Comment: The only part that can cause that error is the subquery compared to `NOT IN (0)` (why not use `<>0`). Here the sections has a primary key of tracjectoryid and sectionid but it is queries with an inequality (`<=`) operator. This can clearly return more than one row (and it did). Can you tell what need to happen when that occurs?

Comment: I get the same error Error in query: ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

Comment: fixed : 0 not IN (Select availableSeats ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reverse the IN operands provided exactly one value 0 is to be checked.

```
..
  AND 0 not IN (
    Select
      availableSeats
    FROM
      sections s3
    WHERE
      s3.trajectId = s1.trajectId
      AND s2.sectionId <= s3.sectionId
      AND s3.sectionId <= s1.sectionId
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

The error was caused by the subquery before the IN clause. The first part returns a result set rather than an expression. Here is the syntax for using IN clause: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/conditions013.htm

On the other hand, you can update the last subquery in the WHERE clause into

```
...
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 
      FROM
      sections s3
    WHERE
      s3.trajectId = s1.trajectId
      AND s2.sectionId <= s3.sectionId
      AND s3.sectionId <= s1.sectionId
      AND s3.availableSeats > 0
)
```